# Conditional Entropy larger than Normal Entropy with dataset

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, entropy, information-theory

I'm working on a dataset stored in `data` whose columns are random variables samples, the last column is the target while the others are the attributes, e.g.

```
data(attribute1, attribute2, target)
```

I'm attempting to compute `H(target | attribute2)` by using the formula for conditional entropy
[image]

The code I have to do this is :

```
def conditional_entropy(X: list, Y: list) -> float:
    """Computes H(Y|X)"""
    h = 0
    for x in X:
        for y in Y:
            p_xy = joint_probability(x, y, X, Y)
            px = probability(x, X)
            if p_xy != 0 and px > 0: h += -p_xy * log2(p_xy / px)
    return h
```

joint probability and probability simply use the uniform probability (number of occurences / total) in the dataset. They're defined as follows :

```
def joint_probability(x: float, y: float, X: list, Y: list) -> float:
    assert len(X) == len(Y)
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if X[i] == x and Y[i] == y: cnt += 1
    return cnt / len(X)

def probability(x: float, X: list) -> float:
    cnt = 0
    for w in X:
        if w == x: cnt += 1
    return cnt / len(X)
```

My sample dataset is :

```
data = np.asarray([ 
        [2, 1, 1], 
        [1, 3, 1],
        [3, 1, 0], 
        [4, 3, 1],
        [3, 2, 0], 
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 0]])
```

And my problem is that I'm getting the following results :

```
print(entropy(data[:, 2])) # 0.9852281360342516
print(conditional_entropy(data[:, 0], data[:, 2])) # 1.9999999999999993
```

Here `data[:, 0] = X`, and `data[:, 2] = Y`

So we have

```
H(Y | X) > H(Y)
```

which is impossible since conditional entropy is always smaller or equal to base entropy. I've checked and rechecked every function and am simply at a loss as to why I'm getting such a result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out I was using the dataset of X and Y to calculate conditional entropy instead of the **support set** of X and Y. Modifying the code to,

```
def conditional_entropy(X: list, Y: list) -> float:
    """Computes H(Y|X)"""
    h = 0
    for x in set(X):
        for y in set(Y):
            p_xy = joint_probability(x, y, X, Y)
            px = probability(x, X)
            if p_xy != 0 and px > 0: h += -p_xy * log2(p_xy / px)
    return h
```

did the trick.